# IIS/Firefox can't display gif file. Error: The image "http://....*.gif" cannot be displayed because it contains error

Tags: firefox, iis

On a window, IIS/firefox displays the directory contents as the follow:

6/29/2014 12:23 AM        38481 _jmeter_latency_06-29-2014-00_23_59.gif
6/29/2014 12:25 AM        42308 _jmeter_latency_06-29-2014-00_25_48.gif

when clicking the gif file, it displays "The image "http://ip/..../*.gif" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Answer (score 0):

http://*.gif doens't work.    I should use image